# Extracting multiple elements from multiple web pages in single function/loop

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm new to web scraping in R and having trouble looping a web scrape to create multiple unique data frames.

From a base URL, I use `map_df` to extract 335 unique URLs from twenty variations on the base URL.

```
# Common basic URL for multiple pages
url_base <- "url_page=%d"

# Function to pull the specific profile URLs part of a common-named series of URLs
map_df(1:20, function(i) {

  pg <- read_html(sprintf(url_base, i))

  urls <- pg %>%
    rvest::html_nodes('body') %>%
    xml2::xml_find_all("//h3[contains(@class, 'heading-large block-tighter')]") %>%
    html_node("a") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rename(url_link = '.')

}) -> url_df # Generates a 335 observation data frame.

urls <- pull(url_df, url_link) # Each URL is unique in composition and length
```

Unlike the base URL, there is not a consistent length or pattern across the 335 extracted URLs.

I create a function, which I know works on a single URL, that extracts three different pieces of the web page. The first piece is a single text string. The second piece is 180 unique text strings. The third piece is 180 unique text/numerics. The data is not organized as a table in the webpage.

```
# Including function that is wrapped up in a `for` loop below
# Extract Data Function ####
extract_data <- function(x) {
  # Read the web page
  rankprofile <- read_html(x) # Single URL from larger URL dataframe

  # Find the data rows in the profile page

  # Extract University/Program Name
  univ_name <- rankprofile %>%
    rvest::html_nodes('body') %>%
    xml2::xml_find_all("//h1[contains(@class, 'hero-heading flex-media-heading')]") %>%
    rvest::html_text() # Extracts 1 text string per page

  # Extract the table categories
  category <- rankprofile %>%
    rvest::html_nodes('body') %>%
    xml2::xml_find_all("//div[contains(@id, 'ddb-field')]") %>%
    xml2::xml_find_all("//span[contains(@class, 'text-coal flex-medium-8')]") %>%
    rvest::html_text() # Extracts 180 unique text strings per page

  # Extract the table values
  value <- rankprofile %>%
    rvest::html_nodes('body') %>%
    xml2::xml_find_all("//div[contains(@id, 'ddb-field')]") %>%
    xml2::xml_find_all("//span[contains(@class, 'text-strong flex-medium-4 medium-end')]") %>%
    rvest::html_text() # Extracts 180 unique stings or numberics per page

  # Remove white space and make the extracts into data frames
  # Also, name columns
  university_name <- univ_name %>%
    str_squish() %>%
    as.data.frame()

  university_name <- university_name %>%
    rename(Value = '.') %>%
    mutate(Category = "University Name") %>%
    select(Category, Value)

  cat_df <- category %>%
    str_squish() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rename(Category = '.')

  val_df <- value %>%
    str_squish() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rename(Value = '.')

  # Bind Category and Value columns
  # Bind Univeristy Name row to Category & Value
  rank_df <- bind_cols(cat_df, val_df) %>%
    bind_rows(university_name)

  return(rank_df)
}
```

And here is where I run into trouble. I try to put the list of 355 URLs into a `for` loop, but it returns a single data frame `rank_df`

```
# Attempting a loop for each unique URL in the `url` object
# but the loop returns a single `rank_df` dataframe instead of 335 dataframes
for (i in 1:335) {
  x <- urls[i]
  extract_rankings(x)
}
```

How can I write the final step to return 355 unique data frames based on the `extract_rankings()` function?

Comment: Can you save each iteration into a list?
     result_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(urls))
     for (i in 1:335) {
       result_list[[i]] <- extract_rankings(urls[i])
     }

Comment: That did it. I then used the following code to get the results lists into a single CSV file:
`lapply(result_list, function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'test.csv'  , append= T, sep=',' ))`